# Excel: Return latest date in a column, with date and spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a log with excel and I want to return the latest date which the log was written.
While I know I can use Max function in excel for a column filled with dates, my table contains both dates and empty spaces.

[image: example of the column]

How should I write VBA / is there any built in function for this?
Thank you!

Comment: It works fine for me when I use `MAX`. What issue are you having with it?

Comment: @Enigmativity my MAX function returned me 45159, and my expression was =MAX(A:A). Are you using any filtering on the column?

Comment: @Enigmativity ohh I made it work, I need to exclude the headers. Thanks!

Comment: 45159 is a date as it is stored by Excel. Max search the top value between the converted date to number. `CDate(45159)` gives the result in the Region and Language Short Date format.

Comment: @JescSH - That's probably not true. You probably just need to format your result properly.

Comment: @Blackcat Ohh you are saying that 45159 correspond to a date in Excel right? how do I convert that number back to date? I tried to use `=CDate()` and it didn't work. How do I do it? Thanks!

Comment: CDate() is a VBA function. On a sheet set the cell's numberformat to Date.

Comment: @JescSH - It doesn't "correspond" because it is already the date. Dates are stored as floating point numbers - you have to apply cell formatting to see them as a date. No conversion is necessary.

Comment: As an aside, you can use the Ctrl-# key combination to display the number as a date. Ctrl-Shift-# removes the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel (and VBA) are stored internally as Numbers (of type Double). The integer value represents the day, counting from 1.1.1900. If the number has a friction part, it represents the time (0.5 is 12:00, .75 is 6pm...)

In Excel, just format the cell as Date: Cells C2 and D2 both contain the same formula, but C2 is formatted as "General" while D2 is formatted as "Short Date" (German settings, so date format is dd.mm.yyyy)

[image]

(Don't worry, the screenshot shows only a part of the data, the result is correct)

In VBA you can simply assign the value that is returned by the `Max`-function to a Date variable:

```
Dim d As Date
d = WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"))
Debug.Print d
```

[image]